# Rails setup oauth2 for coinbase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm new to oauth and I'm trying to setup oauth2 in rails. But whenever I run `rails s` I get.

```
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
Enter the code returned in the URL:
```

I installed the gems and added this code to /config/application.rb

```
require 'oauth2'
redirect_uri = 'my.herokuapp.com/callback'
client = OAuth2::Client.new('eeeeeeeee', 'aaaaaaaaaa', site: 'https://coinbase.com')
`open "#{client.auth_code.authorize_url(redirect_uri: redirect_uri)}"`
print "Enter the code returned in the URL: "
code = STDIN.readline.chomp
token = client.auth_code.get_token(code, redirect_uri: redirect_uri)
puts JSON.parse(token.get('/api/v1/account/balance').body)
```

I'm running this locally and I pointed to my herokuapp. What am I doing wrong? [I'm follwing the tutorial on this page.](https://coinbase.com/docs/api/authentication#collapse1)

Comment: I'm trying to do this now and wish there was more documentation on the subject.

Comment: what are you trying to do i could possible help

Comment: It's kind of complicated so I won't be working on it again until tonight. I'm working on a project where 'hosts' set 'rsvp' prices and users pay the price in btc. There needs to be an escrow function though, so if certain conditions aren't met, the money is returned to the user. Check out this repo: https://github.com/justuseapen/party_starter

Sorry for the lack of a readme.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the gem on Rubygems is pre 2.0 which has OAuth

Use `gem 'coinbase', :git => 'git://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-ruby.git'`

Also see: https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-ruby/issues/38